# Cannot feed value of shape (350,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 7)'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Actually the dimention of my Numpy file id (350,1) and my network is of size (?,7) hpw can i change the shape of my numpy to feed into network?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and form your question properly ?

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it seems you are feeding a 350 size input to a network that can take a 7 size input. There are various ways you can feed input to the network.

1. You can transform input by a weight matrix of size (350 x 7) to reduce the input size to 7.

   2. You can subsample the input to reduce the size,
   3. You can do some other kind of feature extraction to reduce it to the size of 7.

Basically, you will have to in some way reduce the input to size 7 before feeding into the network.

Also, it won't help much if you training data and data you are finally testing come from different sources statistically.

Comment: i applied onehot encoding to do this but my numpy can change to (350, 8) but when i applied (350, 7) i gives an error. do you have any solution of this.?

Comment: I really dont think I understand your comment. What changed to what..? Can you re-read your comment

Comment: Y=y.npy is my numpy file of dimension (350,). i applied onehot encoding on this numpy file. it can be convert in dimension (350,8) but i want to change it to (350,7) according to my network. But i can't convert it.